# Black Screen after login Ubuntu 18.04 Nvidia 418

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I am getting a black screen after logging in on ubuntu 18.04, since updating to nvidia-418 drivers.

The system seems to boot fine until I get the login screen, and it also works fine if I resume through recovery mode. I also got it to work by removing "quiet splash" in the boot options in the grub menu.

Any help/suggestions about this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have so far tried purging and installing nvidia-418 drives a couple of times, and also reinstalling Cuda (which should not matter I guess).
Also ran 

    sudo apt install --reinstall xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418
just in case but it did not help. I could login fine using nouveau drivers, but that was with a terrible resolution.

Comment: I had same problem. It can be solved by changing "nvidia-418" to "nvidia-driver-418".

Answer (score 1):

Switch to LightDM

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

That was the only thing that worked for me.

Here is another interesting (non) solution:
Once the black screen comes up, log in from somewhere else and kill Xorg. Now you're back to the tty. Press ctrl-c to finish killing Xorg. Gdm restarts and will work this time.

Comment: Thanks! But I managed to fix it by removing silent splash line from grub config

Comment: I did this to get my second monitor working. Before, however, I edited /etc/default/grub/ and removed "quiet splash" from "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT". Found this on Nvidia Forums.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooted 18.04 and after login got black screen and no access to terminals. Followed recommendation above and https://medium.com/@zhanghan177/server-boots-into-black-screen-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-18-04-1b9f3a87ee60

From grub menu, selected current ubuntu (default) and hit "e" to edit and removed options "quiet" and "splash" from /boot/vmlinuz line. Shut down power and rebooted and have the gui back.

Answer (score -1):

{**Solved and Works Fine**}

Hey, I had the same problem. I installed the 418.xx driver from the official nvidia site on a fresh 18.04. My internal laptop display froze after login but later I found out that, it was because the graphics card was sending the output to HDMI, because, although my notebook display froze, my external monitor when connected worked fine. I tried disabling HDMI out with xrandr, still no luck.

Then as suggested by *Creator* [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087037/update-to-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-makes-my-laptop-display-not-accessible), I deleted all my xorg.conf files at /etc/X11 and just rebooted. Everything works like a charm. Including my cuda toolkit and tensorflow binaries.

Comment: Sorry didn’t work for me. I don’t really know what the issue is, but I managed to solve it by changing grub config.